# Most concise way to convert Julian date (yyyy[day of year]) to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working with an existing database where all dates are stored as integers in the following format: yyyy[3 digit day of year].

For example:

```
2010-01-01 == 2010001
2010-12-31 == 2010365
```

I'm using the following SQL to convert to a datetime:

```
DATEADD(d, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(
            CAST(NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE AS VARCHAR), 5, LEN(NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE) - 4
        ) AS INT) - 1, 
    CAST('1/1/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE AS VARCHAR),1,4) AS DATETIME))
```

Does anyone have a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Is there a name for this format? Or a better way to refer to it than yyyy[3 digit day of year]?

Comment: @Seth Reno: I thought it was called Julian format, but it's not correct.

Comment: Can you use a view, add a computed column or introduce a procedure to handle the conversion?  Abstracting away the ugly conversion mechanics makes the future nicely concise...

Comment: @Seth: Julian date format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Day_and_year_only

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Why do you say Julian is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it numerically instead of usings strings:

```
dateadd(day, NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE % 1000 - 1,
  dateadd(year, NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE / 1000 - 2000, '2000-1-1')
)
```

(Note that 2010356 is not 2010-12-31 but 2010-12-22. 2010365 is 2010-12-31.)

Comment: Trixy, the second part... I like :)

Answer (score 0):

I think at least one simplification can be made:

```
DATEADD(d, 
    NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE % 1000 - 1, 
    CAST('1/1/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE AS VARCHAR),1,4) AS DATETIME)
)
```

The second term could also be done as follows I think.

```
    CAST('1/1/' + CAST(NEW_BIZ_OBS_DATE/1000 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```